# Exporting Conveyor Belt Animation for Unity

Tags: animation, export, curve-modifier

I modeled and animated conveyor just like in this tutorial. But I don't know how to export it. I would be glad if you help. Thanks. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZDwxGPsfG6E

Answer (score 0):

In Blender,you may want to go to your **preferences** and then **add ons** and enable Import-Export FBX.

This is what the documentation for unity says, and the link to it.

"Unity natively imports Blender files. This works under the hood by using the Blender FBX exporter.
To get started, save your .blend file in your project’s Assets folder. When you switch back into Unity, the file is imported automatically and will show up in the Project View.
To see your model in Unity, drag it from the Project View into the Scene View.
If you modify your .blend file, Unity will automatically update whenever you save.
Unity currently imports

1. All nodes with position, rotation and scale. Pivot points and Names are also imported.
2. Meshes with vertices, polygons, triangles, UVs, and normals.
3. Bones
4. Skinned Meshes
5. Animations"

https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/Manual/HOWTO-ImportObjectBlender.html